# Rails - OAuth::Problem Exception: parameter_absent in LinkedIn API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, linkedin-api

I am Develoing a Linked in APi using Oauth gem. The same gem is working perfectly for my Twitter API, But in the case of Linkedin API, I am getting the request token, and when it tries to get the access token it return the error

> OAuth::Problem Exception: parameter_absent

Code is as follows..

```
    consumerKey         =   "*************************"
    consumerSecret      =   "*************************"
    callbackUrl         =   "http://localhost/"
    apiURL              =   "https://api.linkedin.com"

    request_token_path  =   "/uas/oauth/requestToken"
    access_token_path   =   "/uas/oauth/accessToken"
    authorize_path      =   "/uas/oauth/authorize"


    @consumer           =   OAuth::Consumer.new(consumerKey,consumerSecret, {
                              :site => apiURL,
                              :scheme             => :header,
                              :http_method        => :post,
                              :request_token_path => request_token_path,
                              :access_token_path  => access_token_path,
                              :authorize_path     => authorize_path
                            })


   unless(params["oauth_token"].nil?)
     @request_token  =   session[:request_token] 
     @access_token   =   @request_token.get_access_token
   else
     @request_token  =   @consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callbackUrl)
     firstUrl        =   @request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => callbackUrl)
     session[:request_token] = @request_token
     redirect_to firstUrl
   end
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i did it, ":oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier]" this was the problem :)

```
unless(params["oauth_token"].nil?)
 @request_token  =   session[:request_token] 
 @access_token   =   @request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => params[:oauth_verifier])
else
 @request_token  =   @consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callbackUrl)
 firstUrl        =   @request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => callbackUrl)
 session[:request_token] = @request_token
 redirect_to firstUrl
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, you can fix it by using https://github.com/decioferreira/omniauth-linkedin-oauth2