# Rails Linkedin Omniauth OAuth::Problem, broke with no code change

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, linkedin-api

I'm relatively new to RoR and recently built a working linkedin autorization.

My linkedin OmniAuth connection appears to have broke. It was working perfectly fine for about 12 hours. However, my code base has not changed, but I am now getting the following error.

```
OAuth::Problem

parameter_absent
```

Using rails 3, gem 'omniauth', gem 'omniauth-linkedin'

I have been through these links to no avail:
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/622
[OAuth::Problem (parameter_absent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935441/oauthproblem-parameter-absent)
[Rails - OAuth::Problem Exception: parameter_absent in LinkedIn API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664214/rails-oauthproblem-exception-parameter-absent-in-linkedin-api)

Here is the full trace

```
Started GET "/auth/linkedin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-06 14:58:56 -0400

OAuth::Problem (parameter_absent):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:178:in `request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:194:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
  omniauth-oauth (1.0.1) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb:29:in `request_phase'
  omniauth-linkedin (0.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategies/linkedin.rb:53:in `request_phase'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:207:in `request_call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:174:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.3) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3772833233475588738__call__3008150578280625216__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/joshuakatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/joshuakatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/joshuakatz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/joshuakatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/joshuakatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/joshuakatz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.3ms)
```

Comment: I've reset to an old commit that was definitely working and it is not now. What changes could persist back to an old commit?

Comment: Did u get any solution to this one?